# Map only first occurrence of key/value match in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to map only the first occurrence of key in a dataframe?

Ex:

testDict = { A : 1, B: 2}

df

```
Name   Num
 A
 A
 B
 B
```

Expected output

```
Name   Num
 A      1
 A      
 B      2
 B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [duplicated](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) to find the first occurrence and then [map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['Num'] = df.Name[df.Name.duplicated(keep='last')].map(testDict)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
  Name  Num
0    A  1.0
1    A  NaN
2    B  2.0
3    B  NaN
```

To remove the `NaN` values, if you wish, do:

```
df = df.fillna('')
```

Answer (score 2):

`map` the `drop_duplicates`, assuming you have a unique Index for alignment. (Probably best to keep NaN so the column remains numeric)

```
df['Num'] = df['Name'].drop_duplicates().map(testDict)

  Name  Num
0    A  1.0
1    A  NaN
2    B  2.0
3    B  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `duplicated` and `map`:

```
df['Num'] = np.where(~df['Name'].duplicated(), df['Name'].map(testDict), '')
```

Output:

```
  Name Num
0    A   1
1    A    
2    B   2
3    B
```